# zurb.foundation and disappearing elements

Tags: css, sass, zurb-foundation

I'm using Foundation on my app with section tabs.

I'm experiencing some strange behavior: it happens that tabs won't be displayed sometimes when the site loads. I'm not sure if its because of the low height of browser or not, because after I increase the size of the window the tabs will appear.

When this happens, the following original HTML code:

```
<div data-section="auto" class="section-container-auto tabs">
```

Is replaced with this one (when the tabs become visible):

```
<div data-section="auto" class="section-container-auto tabs" style="min-height: 51px;" data-section-resized="true">
```

Why is that happening? I want to display tabs no matter the browser window height. Is this a bug or is this a normal behavior of Foundation, and how should I resolve it?

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem earlier today.

Adding this line:

```
$(this).foundation('section', 'reflow');
```

inside my $(function() {} seems to have fixed this for me.